# invalid operand '%' - int % int - No pointers involved

Tags: c, binary, int, pic, operands

I'm busy writing some PIC code using SourceBoost IDE and I've been stuck on the following issue for a while now.

I'am attempting to split an integer into digits so it can be sent to a 7seg display however the following error keeps occurring in the following code:

Error:

```
D:\University\Project\PIC_Code.c(81:24): error: failed to generate expression
D:\University\Project\PIC_Code.c(81:24): error: invalid operand '%'
D:\University\Project\PIC_Code.c(81:19): error: failed to generate expression
D:\University\Project\PIC_Code.c(84:11): error: failed to generate expression
D:\University\Project\PIC_Code.c(84:11): error: invalid operand '/'
D:\University\Project\PIC_Code.c(84:6): error: failed to generate expression
```

Variable declarations:

```
int numM;
int numH;
int minutes =0;
int seconds =0;
```

Function in Question

```
void update_clock(void){

numM = minutes;
numH = hours;

int i=0;
int j=0;

while(numM){
    digits_minutes[i]=numM%10;
    i++;

    numM=numM/10;
    }
for(j=i; j<2; j++) digits_minutes=0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are those variables declared globally? Or in a function?

Comment: I'm guessing this "C" compiler for PIC is probably not actually accepting C but some crippled subset of C, perhaps one that lacks division or has odd restrictions on what you can do with division.

Comment: The integer variables numM , numH are declared globally as they are actioned upon elsewhere.

The end game is to convert these integers into binary for output to a port.

Is there some way I could use binary manipulation instead?

Comment: Suspect `numM` is not as it appears.  Create local variable `abc` and try `int abc; ... digits_minutes[i]=abc%10;`

Comment: Does the file that has `update_clock(void)` include a _declaration_ of `numM`?

Comment: chux, I have tried using a local variable declaration, no such luck I'am afraid.

With any other compiler this works fine its just a shame my University will only accept this simulator.

Comment: Yes, the variable is declared at the start of this file of type int.

Comment: The project is on a tight deadline unfortunately so I have had to use a bruteforce work around, it is not very elegant.

The system is tracking clock pulses to keep time, new variable of minutes_Single, minutes_Tens, hours_Single, hours_Tens have been created to catch the double digit overflow.

I will most likely regret this later.

Thankyou for your time

Comment: this line: for(j=i; j<2; j++) digits_minutes=0; is saying to set a non lvalue item (the address of the array digits_minutes) to 0.  suggest using: for(j=i; j<2; j++) digits_minutes[j]=0;

Comment: these two lines in the update_clock() function: numM = minutes;
numH = hours; should be: int numM = minutes; int numH = hours;

Comment: the (global?) array digits_minutes[] does not seem to be defined.

Comment: shouldn't the function update_clock() perform a similar processing for the numH variable as it did for the numM variable?

Comment: how can numH and numM be actioned upon elsewhere when they are initialized to 0, updated and stepped to 0 all within this function, so they would always be 0 outside the scope of this function.

Comment: for efficiency, the variable 'j' can be eliminated and just use 'i' in the last 'for' loop  I.E. for( ; i<2; i++ )

Comment: the code, as displayed, will not successfully compile.  is the compiler set to display all warnings/errors?

Comment: usually, 7 segment displays expect a string of 7 bits (for instance the least significant 7 bits of a byte) which are mapped to the 7 segments of the display, such that each '1' bit in the 7 bits means that segment is to be 'on' however, a binary number (int) such as calculated in the function will not provide such bit mapping